# How to skip a child component during ajax-rendering the parent component?

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces, render

I am using RichFaces. When I ajax-render a `<rich:panel>`, I don't want to render an `<h:inputText>` child of this panel. For example:

```
<rich:panel id="A">
    <h:inputText id="B" value="B" ></h:inputText> 
    <h:inputText id="C" value="C" ></h:inputText> 
    <h:inputText id="D" value="D" ></h:inputText> 
    ...
    <a4j:commandButton id="button"  value="click me" render="A" />
</rich:panel>
```

When I click the button, I intend to render the panel with id="A", but I don't want to render the input text with id="B". How can I render this whole region except of input text with id="B"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INMO

You should add a wrapper to `C` and `D` and render it
like this

```
<h:panelGroup id="CD">
    <h:inputText id="C" value="C" ></h:inputText> 
    <h:inputText id="D" value="D" ></h:inputText> 
</h:panelGroup>
<a4j:commandButton id="button"  value="click me" render="CD" />
```

Or just specify their ids directly in the `render` attribute , like this

```
<a4j:commandButton id="button"  value="click me" render="C D" />
```

Comment: Is there anything like this: <h:inputText id="B" value="B" sikp_render="true"></h:inputText>

Comment: Nope , there isn't such a thing

Comment: Not in RichFaces, no, but in PrimeFaces you can use "PrimeFaces Selectors" for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614882/how-to-exclude-child-component-in-ajax-update-of-a-parent-component/12619539#12619539