# exclude component from process when form is submited (works in h:panelGrid but not in p:panelGrid)

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

Q: What syntax should i use to exclude a component when submitting a form using primefaces?

Using the process attribute i know how to include components.

```
<h:inputText id="included"/>
<p:commandButton value="button" process="included" actionListener="#{myBean.doStuff}/>
```

I've been trying to play around with syntax similiar to what is used in the answer here: [How to exclude child component in ajax update of a parent component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614882/how-to-exclude-child-component-in-ajax-update-of-a-parent-component) but cant get it to work

```
<h:inputText id="notIncluded" styleClass="notIncluded"/>
<p:commandButton ... process="@(form :not(.notIncluded))"/>
```

Edit (doing the homework and adding an actual working example):
On glassfish 3.1.2.2 and primefaces 3.4.2

When i looked further, the exclusion works fine inside h:panelGrid

```
<h:form id="aForm">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:inputText id="inc" styleClass="included" required="true" />
        <p:message for="inc" />
        <p:inputText id="notInc" styleClass="notIncluded" required="true" />
        <p:message for="notInc" />

        <p:commandButton value="submit" process="@(form :not(.notIncluded))"
            update=":aForm" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

But is no longer excluded inside a similar p:panelGrid

```
<h:form id="aForm">
    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:inputText id="inc" styleClass="included" required="true" />
        <p:message for="inc" />
        <p:inputText id="notInc" styleClass="notIncluded" required="true" />
        <p:message for="notInc" />

        <p:commandButton value="submit" process="@(form :not(.notIncluded))"
            update=":aForm" />
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Comment: which version Primefaces you are using? have you placed in a single h:form as Balus example? Another suggestion that you can add additionaly '@this' too so commandButton will be executed.

Comment: Yeah you are right, i removed the information that didnt make it work :) updating in a sec..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have checked your examples, if you review page source your will notice that `p:panelGrid` creates table with id. Little bit strange but *jQuery selector* doesnt access childs when table has an id. If I remove table Id then button works fine. So my solution was giving an id to `panelGrid` and using this id in selector. `p:panelGrid` will give same id to table but you need to make sure you add `prependId="false"` attribute into your h:form:

```
<h:form id="aForm" prependId="false">
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="myGrid">
        <p:inputText id="inc" styleClass="included" required="true" />
        <p:message for="inc" />
        <p:inputText id="notInc" styleClass="notIncluded" required="true" />
        <p:message for="notInc" />

        <p:commandButton value="submit" process="@(#myGrid :not(.notIncluded))"
            update=":aForm" />
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```