# Excluding fields from JSF 'process' event

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, jquery-selectors

I have multiple forms on a page, one of which is processed when a specific button is pressed. However I have a couple of fields in this form that I don't actually want to be processed. I have this so far:

In an xhtml template

```
<h:form id="formX">
     <ui:insert name="formX"/>
</h:form>
```

in an xhtml file that uses this template

```
<ui:define name="formX">
    <p:commandButton process="@(#formX :not('.dontProcess')"/>

    <p:inputText.../>
    <p:inputText.../>
    <p:inputText.../>
    <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="dontProcess"/>
    <p:inputText styleClass="dontProcess"/>
</ui:define>
```

but the last inputText and the selectOneMenu are still processed. Is the syntax in the process attribute correct? Is it legitimate to have a jQuery :not() selector after #formX? Is there any easier way to stop these fields being processed by JSF?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exclude child component in ajax update of a parent component?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614882/how-to-exclude-child-component-in-ajax-update-of-a-parent-component) this works for `process` as well as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14073406/1065197

Comment: I read both of those prior to asking the question, they gave me the basis for the failed solution above...they dont work for me, I think it's because I'm not just using @(form :not(.dontProcess)) because I have multiple forms

Comment: Not sure if is a typo but you have `@(#formX` instead of `@(formX`.

Comment: its not a typo, its the id of the form

Comment: I mean, you have a `#` (read my comment again [: ).

Comment: yes....#formX is intentional, in the same way that .dontProcess is intentional

Comment: From possible duplicate link, BalusC (JSF expert) uses `@(form` and not `@(#form`. Have you tried this?

Comment: 'form' refers to the form you are in...my '#formX' refers to a specific form id that I am referencing...I can't use simply 'form' because I have multiple forms and I'm not actually in the one I want

Comment: So you want to process data from an external `<h:form>`?

Comment: did you look at my example?

Comment: its annoying that you have said this question may have already been answered...because it hasnt, and now no one will bother answering it

Comment: but nobody vote it as a duplicate either