# In JSF is there any way to validate a component that is not an EditableValueHolder?

Tags: validation, jsf-2

This is a more generic version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14385376/516433).  In general, can I cause a JSF lifecycle validation to occur on an element that does not implement `EditableValueHolder`.  This seems like a silly question, but there are widget libraries that seem to supply widgets that have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot force a validation to occur on it directly. You need to wrap it in a class that implements EditableValueHolder. Then you create and register the Validator for that type.