# Browser clientID is not accepted for FacesMessage

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have several `<p:messages>` elements that ought to handle different types of errors produced by a single bean. Now the clientID I get from my browser for one element is always the same, since there are no generated ids inside (that is 3 IDs altogether).

No matter which clientID I pass to FacesContext.addMessage(), I will always end up displaying all error messages on **every** `<p:messages>` element.

One clientID as in browser: `regelDetailAccordion:duoDlgForm2:regelDetail`
another clientID as in browser: `regelDetailAccordion:duoDlgForm1:messagesNeuerFehler`
Bean code: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(X, new FacesMessage(...));` 
where `X` is clientID (not) preceded by `:` and/or only `regelDetail` with and without `:` in front. Tried all :(

Dialog-Include:

```
<ui:insert name="insertDuo"><ui:include src="/includes/duoRegelStmt.xhtml" />
</ui:insert>
```

Dialog that displays all my `messages`:

```
    <p:dialog widgetVar="newDuoDialog" id="newDuoDlg" modal="true">
        <p:layout id="layout">
            <p:layoutUnit position="west">
                <ui:insert name="insertDetailStmt">
                    <h:form id="stmtDetailForm">
                        <ui:include src="/includes/stmtDetail.xhtml" /> <!-- left side -->
                    </h:form>
                </ui:insert>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <ui:insert name="insertDetailRegel">
                    <ui:include src="/includes/regelDetail.xhtml"/> <!-- right side -->
                </ui:insert>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </p:dialog>
```

Right side of the dialog that displays 2 of my 3 `messages`:

```
<ui:composition>
    <h:panelGrid id="unterheaderUndAccordion">
        <h:panelGrid rendered="#{...}" id="regelUnterheader"/>
        <p:accordionPanel multiple="true" activeIndex="0,1" id="regelDetailAccordion" rendered="#{...}">
            <p:tab>
                <h:form id="duoDlgForm1">
                    <ui:insert name="neuerFehler">
                        <ui:include src="/includes/neuerFehler.xhtml" />
                    </ui:insert>

                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{regelBean.selectedFehlerCode}" id="selFCode"
                        onChange="submit()" process="@this" valueChangeListener="#{regelBean.changeFehlerCode}">
                        <p:ajax event="change" update="duoDlgForm1" />
                        <f:selectItems ... />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </h:form>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab>
                <h:form id="duoDlgForm2">
                    <h:panelGrid>
                        <p:messages id="regelDetail" showDetail="true" closable="true"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:form>
            </p:tab>
        </p:accordionPanel>
    </h:panelGrid>
</ui:composition>
```

neuerFehler contains a `messages` that is defined like this

```
<p:messages id="messagesNeuerFehler" showDetail="true" closable="true"/>
```

In my thinking, when I enter the correct value for `X`, only the proper messages field will display a message, even if other `messages` are updated. If that is true, what is the correct clientID I have to enter? Big thanks in advance, I'm at wit's end :(

[image: Screeny]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly you may prevent certain components from being updated using Primefaces Selectors like this:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText ... />
    <h:inputText ... />
    <h:inputText ... styleClass="noupdate" />
    <h:inputText ... />
    <h:inputText ... />
    <p:commandButton ... update="@(form :not(.noupdate))"/>
</h:form>
```

Original answer by BalusC [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614882/how-to-exclude-child-component-in-ajax-update-of-a-parent-component).

If this doesen't help, can you use the for-attribute on the messages component? Seems to me that you expect the clientid in the FacesMessage to be the identifier of the messages component, when it is the identifier for the component with error. Sorry if I misunderstand.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Your message"));
```

and add a `update="elementId"` attribute to the component, which triggers your managed bean action.

"elementId", of course, is the coresponding id of your `<p:messages>` element.

For me this way it works fine. Maybe it also solves your issue.

Comment: but what if my buttons that update already update a bigger scope which contains more than one `messages` ?

Comment: That will be a problem, because all components inside your update component will be updated. You could try to update only needed ones. Could be a lot but you can separate them by spaces in your update attribute. I don't know if this will work for you. Can you provide the code with your buttons, too?

Comment: I understand your point but I somehow doubt this is the way to go, although it might work. I mean, obviously `X` is not supposed to be `null`

Comment: I didn't say that this is the definitve way to go. I just tell you how it is described in the PrimeFaces documentation and the way I handle this issue.

Comment: I know you didnt say that ;) What part of the documentation are you talking about?

Comment: Well, everytime they use `<p:messages>` or `<p:growl>` they set this parameter `null` and add a `update="id"` attribute instead.