# Prevent a p:selectOneListbox from being submitted inside h:form

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to skip an input component inside a `h:form` from being processed/submitted as it is kept there only for pure presentational needs & does not submit value to any bean field. How do I disable its submittion along with other form inputs while the form is submitted?

```
      <h:form>
            <!--other input components-->

            <p:selectOneListbox id="deptsSel">
                <f:selectItems value="#{listRetriever.list}"
                               var="dept" itemLabel="#{namesDirectory.getName(dept)}" itemValue="#{dept}" />
            </p:selectOneListbox>

            <!--other input components-->
      </h:form>
```

I omitted the value attribute for `p:selectOneListbox` but while submitting the form it still gives validation error: "`deptsSel: Validation Error: Value is not valid`"

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614882/how-to-exclude-child-component-in-ajax-update-of-a-parent-component.

Comment: Why are you worried about it? If you're not using that component in your bean, just leave it alone

Comment: What are you using to submit the form, a command button ?

Comment: @BalusC: you deleted your answer, so I'm afraid if I asked for something that's not feasible or is it?

Comment: I realized I misunderstood your comment. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable it during [postback](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isPostback()) as long as it's not [rendering the response](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getCurrentPhaseId()).

```
<p:selectOneListbox ... disabled="#{facesContext.postback and facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal ne 6}">
```

As part of JSF safeguard against hacked requests, the [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) component's `disabled` attribute is namely also obeyed during request processing through all phases in the JSF lifecycle, including validations phase.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, might you be interested in knowing when and why exactly that particular validation error would occur, head to [Validation Error: Value is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069379/validation-error-value-is-not-valid). This is namely a strong hint that your model is broken — even though you never intented to update the model, it can still have its consequences elsewhere in the chain.

Comment: Thanks, however I get disabled input component when I try to ajax update it. I need to disable it only when form is submitted not when it is updated via ajax .